# Storing password in the client side using Appcelerator - Design Approach

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I am creating an application using Appcelerator wherein the user needs to enter the username and password to login. Once logged in, the user can enable TouchID for authentication. After logging out, the user can use the TouchID for authentication and use the application.

My flow is that once the username and password is provided, I store those two information in Keychain using the following module [iOS Keychain Module](https://github.com/pegli/ti_keychain). Then I use ti.touchid to authenticate the fingerprint, if success, then I retrieve the username and password from keychain and then send it over HTTPS web service call and login the user to the application.

My query is that, whether this is an acceptable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an iOS developer nor does any ti or keychain terms mean anything to me at all. That's for a start and to reduce the number of down votes i might get.

In terns of security, I would suggest that you imagine obtaining that particular user's phone where you know you have some authentication credentials stored. Let's say I am a user of your app, already logged-in and have my credentials saved somewhere on my device, and you obtain this phone by stealing it from me.

Now, will you be able to access my account in anyway? Will a hacker with access to the physical phone be able to retrieve any information stored in your Keychain storage?

If so, If you can think of anyway to do so, then *your approach is not valid*.

I understand you want to save users sometime by making sure they can login with just their fingerprint, which is a valid reason to think of such an approach, but you will have to think everything in terms of reverse engineering.

Additional recommendations would be using an on-the-fly hash to store information in the Keychain and making sure to check that before restoring the same. For example, user credentials saved on "home wifi" can be verified with your fingerprint only "at home" on the same wifi network where the same will be invalid on a different network.

i.e)
(keychainItem.x = y) is TRUE ONLY IF (something else)

where this (something else) is something that will prevent hackers from accessing the Keychain even if they have access to the device itself.

I do this myself when programming web applications with stored cookies. I for example use a stored cookie ONLY IF it is being accessed from the same IP it was saved from. Anytime that IP address changes, user will have to re-authenticate even if the cookie values are correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like your approach Ruslan. Some pointer which you have mentioned is good to keep in mind while designing such approach. But I will keep the question open to get in some more thoughts before marking an answer.

Comment: Sure @Soumya, glad that helped and good luck with your endeavors.